# How to horizontally center a bootstrap button group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to center the button group to the top of the page. I tried adding custom css and a margin: 0 auto to it but it did not help. Any suggestions? Thanks
(I'm using bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6)

html:

```
    <head>

        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css">

        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="application.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="header">

            <div id="logo">

                Logo

            </div>

            <div id="button-container" class="btn-group">

                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 4</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#button-container {
    width: 333px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well button group is an `inline-block` element so just put it inside a `class="text-center"` container, either the header itself or a separate div like this demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="header">

  <div id="logo">

    Logo

  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div id="button-container" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="header" class="text-center">

  <div id="logo">

    Logo

  </div>
  <div id="button-container" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 4</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: the inline-block comment made me realize my btn-group wasn't centering itself because I had added the btn-block class. Without it and your trick it flows perfectly. Using `<div class="text-center text-md-left">` for responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something as follows,

```
#button-container {
    width: 333px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;   
    left:50%;  /*MODIFICATION*/
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /*MODIFICATION*/
}
```

```css
#button-container {
    width: 333px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;   
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
 <head>

        <title>Title</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="header">

            <div id="logo">

                Logo

            </div>

            <div id="button-container" class="btn-group">

                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 4</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to accepted answer except, the **buttons are always** `center aligned` even when they take up multiple lines on a small device (or resolution).

```css
.btn-group-vertical>.btn, 
.btn-group>.btn {
    float: unset !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="logo">Logo</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <div id="button-container" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button Text 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button Text 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button Text 3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button Text 4</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button Text 5</button>
    </div>
</div>
```